# FastExport Utility in Teradata

Tags: teradata, fastexport

Can anybody please let me know how I can use FastExport utility inside a stored procedure to export data from a table in Teradata to an FTP server. Basically, whenever I call this proc, it should export the entire data in a table to the FTP location (which I should be able to provide in the proc) in text format.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't.  You would need to write a script that uses FastExport to build your resultset, and store it or move it to your desired location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile an external stored procedure which connects to a separate server which contains the FastExport along with FastExport utility installed and invoke the utility remotely.
You can use a simple SSH command for that purpose.

I have never tried that personally. There are restriction on I/O calls which can be made using a custom stored procedure and also on usage of Standard C library. Similar restrictions apply to Java. But I believe SSH command and sockets are something available to a general user and must be available in the custom stored procedure. You will need to experiment a bit.

See Teradata Documentation "SQL External Routine Programming" - Chapter 2 for C/C++ or Chapter 5 for Java.